# Haskell - generating all paths between nodes

Tags: haskell

I need to build a function, which return all paths between certain nodes.

`connect  :: Int -> Int-> [[(Int,Int)]]`

Data.Graph library gives me usefull function 'buildG' which builds graph for me. If I call

`let g = buildG (1,5) [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(2,5)]`,

I will get an array where every node is mapped to his neighbours.
An example:

```
g!1 = [2]
g!2 = [3,5] 
..
g!5 = []
```

I was trying to do it using list comprehensions, but I am not very good in haskell and I am 
getting typing error which I can't repair.

```
connect x y g 
    | x == y = []
    | otherwise = [(x,z) | z <- (g!x), connect z y g]
```

I don't need to worry at this moment about cycles. Here is what I want to get:

```
connect 1 5 g = [[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)],[(1,2),(2,5)]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Think recursively. A path from `s` to `e` is composed of a first edge `(s,t)` and a path from `t` to `e`, unless `s == e`, in which case a path shall be empty. So a first attempt is

```
connect x y g
    | x == y    = [[]]
    | otherwise = [(x,t):path | t <- g!x, path <- connect t y g]
```

The list of all eligible paths from a node to itself is the list with the single element `[]`, in the other cases, we obtain the list of all eligible paths by the logic above, pick a first edge and find the paths from its end.

The problem is that cycles will cause it to hang. To avoid that, you have to remember which nodes you already have visited, and not explore paths from that on:

```
connect x y g = helper x y g [x]
  where
    helper a b g visited
        | a == b    = [[]]
        | otherwise = [(a,c):path | c <- g!a, c `notElem` visited, path <- helper c b g (c:visited)]
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I said I didn't need to worry about cycles, but anyway thanks ;-)